# How to skip first line while reading the csv in vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
 Try

            If Not MyCache.GetInstance.AzureCacheOn Then
                reader = New IO.StreamReader(FilePathUtility.GetInstance.MapPath(objUrl))
            Else

                request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(objUrl)
                response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
                strm = DirectCast(response.GetResponseStream, IO.Stream)
                reader = New IO.StreamReader(strm)
            End If

            Dim list = New List(Of String)()

            Using reader
                Dim line As String
                While (InlineAssignHelper(line, reader.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
                    list.Add(line)
                End While
            End Using


            lines = list.ToArray()



        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try



 Private Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function
```

I have this code snippet which is working fine but now in csv file i need to add some information in first line so i need to skip the first line how I can do that please help screenshot of csv is attached[image: First Line skip]

Comment: what happens when u call reader.ReadLine() once before while ?

Comment: @Yvette c# will help too i will change in vb

Comment: Sry about nxt time it wont hpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call read line before while, also check if the line is not blank and then only go to loop.
This will skip your first line.

Code something like :

```
Using reader
    Dim line As String
    // if reader.ReadLine() is not empty
         While (InlineAssignHelper(line, reader.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
             list.Add(line)
         End While
    // end if
End Using
```

To skip nth line (2nd in your case) use :

```
     Using reader
        Dim line As String
        // count = 0, n = 1 // 0 = first line, 1 = 2nd line etc
        While (InlineAssignHelper(line, reader.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
             // if(count++ != n)                
                 list.Add(line)
             // end if
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: it is working but i need that heading sorry i must have ask the second line only

Comment: Check the updated code, now u can skip any line you want (0 for 1st and so on)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `ReadLine` once before you start processing the lines:

```
Using reader
    reader.ReadLine())
    Dim line As String
    While (InlineAssignHelper(line, reader.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
        list.Add(line)
    End While
End Using
```